# How to use the IEEEtran.bst style?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieeetran

I apologize in advance for the localized content and long error log in this question.

I am writing a journal paper using the [IEEE template](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/).

I made a minimal example to demonstrate my problems with the **IEEEtran.bst** style:

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Citation \cite{IEEEhowto:article_typical}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{IEEEabrv,IEEEexample}

\end{document}
```

When I run **BibTex** on this source I get errors such as:

```
*****
*****     BibTeX output: 
*****     cd "/home/martin/My articles/Minimum_example"
*****     bibtex example
*****
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: example.aux
The style file: IEEEtran.bst
"<" can't start a style-file command---line 2 of file IEEEtran.bst
 : 
 : <!-- saved from url=(0085)ftp://ftp.u-aizu.ac.jp/pub/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran.bst -->
(Error may have been on previous line)
&lt; is an unknown function---line 584 of file IEEEtran.bst
&gt; is an unknown function---line 585 of file IEEEtran.bst
&gt; is an unknown function---line 591 of file IEEEtran.bst
&gt; is an unknown function---line 618 of file IEEEtran.bst
&lt; is an unknown function---line 768 of file IEEEtran.bst
&gt; is an unknown function---line 776 of file IEEEtran.bst
&gt; is an unknown function---line 1161 of file IEEEtran.bst
&gt; is an unknown function---line 1241 of file IEEEtran.bst
&gt; is an unknown function---line 1247 of file IEEEtran.bst
&gt; is an unknown function---line 1249 of file IEEEtran.bst
&gt; is an unknown function---line 1256 of file IEEEtran.bst
&gt; is an unknown function---line 1264 of file IEEEtran.bst
&gt; is an unknown function---line 2386 of file IEEEtran.bst
Database file #1: IEEEabrv.bib
Database file #2: IEEEexample.bib
-- IEEEtran.bst version 1.13 (2008/09/30) by Michael Shell.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/
-- See the "IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf" manual for usage information.
ptr=1, stack=
500
---the literal stack isn't empty for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2418 of file IEEEtran.bst
4 is an integer literal, not a string or missing field, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
4 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
2 is an integer literal, not a string or missing field, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
2 is an integer literal, not a string or missing field, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
2 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
0 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
0 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
0 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
0 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
0 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
0 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
0 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
0 is an integer literal, not a string or missing field, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
0 is an integer literal, not a string or missing field, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
0 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
53 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst
ptr=16, stack=

54

57

45

53

55

49

pp.
20
\emph{{IEEE} Electron Device Lett.}
---the literal stack isn't empty for entry IEEEexample:article_typical
while executing---line 2421 of file IEEEtran.bst

Done.
"<" can't start a style-file command---line 2428 of file IEEEtran.bst
 : 
 : </pre></body></html>
(Error may have been on previous line)
(There were 33 error messages)
```

When I compile the document with **pdflatex regardless of this error**, I get a wrong output. The names of multiple authors are separated by "and" instead of commas and there is information missing:

**Incorrect (actual):**

[image]

**Correct**

[image]

How can I repair this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you downloaded the `.bst` file it was saved as an `html` file. This is why you have the  lines

```
<!-- saved from url=(0085)ftp://ftp.uaizu.ac.jp/pub/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran.bst -->
```

and

```
</pre></body></html>
```

Open the `IEEEtran.bst` with a text editor and remove the `html` lines. Alternatively, download it again and ensure it is not saved as an `html` file (it might depend on the browser you use and the way you save it).

Comment: Thank you! I did as you said and it works. I have to be more careful. You helped me a LOT.

Answer (score 2):

You can get lastest updated version from

http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran.bst

If you are using linux to get raw use:

```
wget http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran.bst
```

Comment: In general we are asked on to link directly to CTAN servers but to use the mirror network: `mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran.bst`